# Приложение сайта

Tags: android

Как написать приложение видеохостинга,например fs.to? Делал плеер для андроид? Очевидно,знаний мало, то что мне стоит изучить? Просто интересно было бы это сделать .

Comment: Ваш вопрос не ясен. Из вашей формулировки можно лишь предположить что существует некий сайт, на коем хранится видео. Что должно делать приложение - не ясно совсем.

Comment: да,простите. Есть сайт для просмотра фильмов онлайн,я хочу сделать  приложение на андроид,которое будет изображать этот сайт,только в удобной для телефона форме, ну как мобильная версия вк,например.

Comment: *у меня есть компьютер, как мне написать GTA 5?*

Answer (score 3):

Это называется "нативное приложение", смысл в том, чтобы не парсить сайт  - а обращаться через API напрямую к базе. Это в разы ускоряет скорость работы + можно добавить фичи самого андроида.

Чтобы написать подобное приложение, вам нужен целый комплекс знаний, начните со следующих тем:

Жизненный цикл `Activity`, обработка поворота экрана, `Fragments`, жизненный цикл `Fragments`, `Service`, `SQlite`,работа с  `API` сайта, работа с сетью и тд(к моменту `API` вы уже будете иметь представление, в какую сторону смотреть).

Для начала вам помогут ресурсы:

[Старт андроид](http://www.fandroid.info/)

[Дев колибри](http://devcolibri.com/)

По ходу так же вам придется цеплять верстку под `Android` , разные компоновщики лаяутов, стили, `Material design`.

Comment: спасибо, знаю про все, кроме api)
Простите за глупые вопросы, а как мне узнать, где api конкретного сайта?
А что, если такого нет?

Comment: @ОлегКунецкий http://computercraft.ru/wiki/Fs_(API) если нет, то можно парсить, но вообще идея плохая.

Лучше придумать какую либо другую идею.